# Nginx doesn't start

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, vps

I try to start my Nginx and I get the below error after the below command:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/nginx start

Starting nginx: start-stop-daemon: unable to start /usr/local/nginx (Permission denied)
```

My config file is:

```
user www-data www-data;
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  2048;
}

http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    access_log  off

    sendfile        on;
    tcp_nopush      on;
    tcp_nodelay     off;
    keepalive_timeout  10;

    gzip  on;
    gzip_comp_level 2;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_types      text/plain text/css application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;


    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;

        location / {
            root   html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }

        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }

    }
        include /usr/local/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
    }
```

Comment: What process did you follow to install nginx?

Comment: wget http://nginx.org/download/nginx-1.2.3.tar.gz
tar xvfz nginx-1.2.3.tar.gz
cd nginx-1.2.3
./configure 
make
sudo make install

Comment: Your system hasn't got a package manager? Do you use [LFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_From_Scratch)?

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
chmod +x /usr/local/nginx
```